# Unable to connect to SQL server in AWS from SQL server Management studio

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services

I created a Microsoft windows server 2012 R2 with SQL server express on AWS. I then created a new login with SQL server authentication.

Though I am able to connect to the sql server instance if I RDP into the server, I am not able to connect from my machine. I tried the following

*public ip of AWS instance*/SQLEXPRESS
*public ip of AWS instance*
*public ip of AWS instance*:1433

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely need to open the windows 2012 firewall on port 1433, *AND* modify the security group that is controlling that instance to ALSO allow traffic thru on port 1433.

Both the firewall (if its running) and the security group need to be opened.

Once you open the security group, and confirm you can connect, you may want to think if that is really what you want - leaving it open to the world is inviting trouble. Best to open it only when needed and/or (as I do), ,restrict incoming traffic to port 1433 ONLY from known IP's, i.e. the ip address of your home/work computer.

Comment: Hi, I already have the security group configure for 1433.and I also see an Inbound rule for 1433 port in windows firewall .

Answer (score 0):

in AWS PRIOR to creating database, create a security group which has your ip address; THEN create the stinking database.  (2 weeks of frustration) also - go into your firewall and make sure the port is open for in/outbound. 1433 in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to enabling **SQL Server Authentication** through **SQL Management Studio**. Follow these steps to enable SQL Server Authentication:

- Open SQL Server Management Studio.
- Connect to the SQL Server instance you would like to use.
- In the Object Explorer, right-click the server, and then click Properties.
- On the Security page, under Server authentication, select **SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode**, and then click OK.
- In the Object Explorer, right-click your server, and then click Restart. If the SQL Server Agent is running, it must also be restarted.